# Https issue in Edge with IE mode

Tags: internet-explorer, https

I have sliver light application which works only IE and company decided to start using Edge for this app. We have enabled IE mode in Edge browser and app works perfectly loads except the https part. This site is secured site with SHA256 certification but it displays "Not Secure" message in Edge browser when we run the app in IE mode. Please let me know if anyone had similar issue and how did you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're experiencing the same thing described in [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/ie-mode-quot-not-secure-quot-on-some-parts-of-intranet-site/m-p/2617567/highlight/true#M3631). Is there any http-served content in your https page? If so, it will show "Not Secure" in Edge IE mode. Actually, in this situation, it will also show not secure in IE by hiding the lock icon from the address bar. Please check if the lock icon shows in IE.

Besides, according to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/ie-mode-quot-not-secure-quot-on-some-parts-of-intranet-site/m-p/2778693/highlight/true#M3801), the default reference links to the Silverlight support pages are `http`. You need to change them to `https`.

In a conclusion, please make sure there's no http content in your pages.

Comment: I saw the first article before but didn't notice the last comment thoroughly. It fixed my issue after modifying http urls to https urls. Thank you so much